# How to trigger (window).focus on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, detection, blur

When the page is loaded the focus/blur state isn't activated. When switching to for example another tab `blur` show, and upon switching back to the page `focus` activates – but at first load of the page none of the states are activated, why? Is this expected behavior or have I messed something up?

```
$(function(){
$(window).focus(function() {
        document.title="focus";
    });

    $(window).blur(function() {
        document.title="blur";
    });
});
```

**Update**
Seems like Adding `}).focus();` as suggested by Rory in the comments **doesn't** make any difference anymore due to changes in browsers – so I'm still looking for a way to detect focus on page load.

**Update 2**
I've added an onload to act as a "pretend focus", so far this is the best I've managed to come up with. Don't know if this a reasonable solution, so if you've got a better one I'd love to take part of it.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.title="focus";
};

window.onblur = function() {
    document.title="blur";
};

window.onfocus = function() {
    document.title="focus";
};
```

Comment: On first load of the page it already has focus, therefore no event is raised.

Comment: This also appears to be browser dependent - Firefox gives me a focus event with your code, Chrome doesn't.

Comment: @Antares42 I agree, the behavior seems very erratic.